# Sklearn decision tree occasionally returns different predictions even when random state is set to a constant

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have built a decision tree and have set "random_state = 2000"

However, when I rerun the model on the a specific row of the test dataset for a number of times, the prediction (clf.predict_proba) is occasionally identical but occasionally completely different.

Also, there is no randomization in the train/test split.

How can I ensure consistent predictions upon rerunning the model on the same data?

Comment: It won't be possible to debug this behavior without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

try fixing the random seed before running the prediction (if this doesn't work at the beginning of the script). This should fix any stochasticity in the evaluation of the predict_proba method (I don't know if there is any...):

```
np.random.seed(2000)
clf.predict_proba(X)
```

I also can't reproduce this error in sklearn 0.20.3 so try upgrading to this version if using an earlier one. If neither of these fix the problem, I suspect that there is a bug elsewhere in your code...